# Insert table as fragment with parameters

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have a table and fragment on on childFragment.html

```
<div th:fragment="firstTable">
<table border="2">
<tbody>
<tr th:each="rt : ${fragment}">
<td th:text="${rt.id}"></td>
<td th:text="${rt.number}"></td>
<td th:text="${rt.number2}"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

How can I insert it in the another html page?

Comment: Take a look at [parameterized fragments](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#parameterizable-fragment-signatures). I think that is what you need. See also [these SO questions and answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=thymeleaf+parameterized+fragments+site%3Astackoverflow.com) for more examples.

Comment: What have you tried? There is documentation on [using fragments](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout) (w/parameters).